# How to make a Map object from Field(reflect) with all values?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a field annotated with the MaskedMap annotation and it is a Map class.
Then I get this field through the annotation search and I want to get all the values of this field that are in the Map. And I can't make from field to Map

```
private void putMapParamsMasks(Class<?> type) {
                    for (Field field : type.getDeclaredFields()) {
                        MaskedMap maskedMap = field.getAnnotation(MaskedMap.class);
                        if (maskedMap != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < maskedMap.keys().length; i++) {
                                try {
                                    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) field.get(new HashMap<String,String>()); //failed
                                    valueMasks.put(map.get(maskedMap.keys()[i]), maskedMap.masks()[i].newInstance());
                                } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                                    throw new UnexpectedException(e);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
Map<String, String> map =(Map<String, String>) field.get(type);
```

But I caught it

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Map field com.ConfirmRequest.params to null value
```

Comment: Why are you passing `new HashMap<String,String>()` as a parameter to `field.get`? `field` is a field of `Class<?> type`. You need to pass an instance of `type` as a parameter. And that is not `HashMap` since that does not have your custom `MaskedMap` annotation in it.

Comment: I tried to do it on your advice, but I caught another exception

Answer (score 0):

The right solution, you need to use the Object itself

```
private void maskedMapProcess(Object value) {
                        for (Field field : value.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                            MaskedMap maskedMap = field.getAnnotation(MaskedMap.class);
                            if (maskedMap != null) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < maskedMap.keys().length; i++) {
                                    field.setAccessible(true);
                                    try {
                                        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) field.get(value);
                                        valueMasks.put(map.get(maskedMap.keys()[i]), maskedMap.masks()[i].newInstance());
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        throw new UnexpectedException(e);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```